# ls: cannot access *.jpg: No such file or directory

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a variable with a list of files in it so that I can iterate through them. I'm doing so like this:

```
FILES=(`ls *.jpg`)
FILES="${FILES[@]}"
```

When I run this script, it simply throws:

```
ls: cannot access *.jpg: No such file or directory
```

I've looked at some other answers for issues similar to this, and I'm fairly sure this isn't a permissions issue, as adding `sudo` to the front doesn't have any effect and I am `root`. I've also checked the permissions on the script itself and they are `-rwxr-xr-x`, so I think I'm good there.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. There are some .jpg files in the directory you are running your script?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? For most purposes the first line would be better done as `FILES=(*.jpg)` (see [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)), and the second line mixes treating `FILES` as an array and as a plain variable in a way that doesn't make any sense (and will have bad consequences).

Answer (score 1):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code demonstrates how to reliably populate a Bash array with a list of files:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s nullglob   # Make globs that match nothing expand to nothing
shopt -s dotglob    # Make globs match files whose names start with dot

files=( *.jpg )

declare -p files
```

- [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) can find many problems with Bash (and other shell) code.  If you put a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line on the code in the question and submit it to [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) it identifies several problems.
- `shopt -s nullglob` prevents glob patterns like `*.jpg` expanding to themselves when they match nothing.  Such an expansion was the cause of the error message shown in the question.  There were no '.jpg' files in the directory where the code was run, `ls` was given a literal argument of `*.jpg`, and it correctly complained that the file `*.jpg` does not exist.
- Using `shopt -s nullglob` with the code in the question would not work because running it in a directory with no `.jpg` files would cause it to create a list of *all* of the files that were in the directory (except the ones whose names begin with a dot).  The list would be garbled if any of the file names contained spaces or glob patterns.  Files whose names started with '-' would cause `ls` to do unexpected things.
  It's usually unnecessary to use the output of `ls` in Bash programs, and it's often dangerous to use it.  See [why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3))](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).
- `shopt -s dotglob` ensures that files whose  names begin with a dot (e.g. '.image.jpg') will be included in the list.  Don't use if you don't want that.
- I replaced `FILES` with `files` because uppercase variable names risk clashes with environment variables or shell builtin variables.  See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375).
- `declare -p files` just prints the value of `files` in a clear and unambiguous way.

Comment: Note that `nullglob` can have unexpected effects; for example `ls /some/nonexistent/dir/*.jpg` would normally print a "No such file or directory" error, but with `nullglob` it'll list the contents of the current working directory instead. So I recommend turning it off with `shopt -u nullglob` after you need it.